# php mail function not showing hour

Tags: php, email

I am reading values from the post and sending them via mail(). Now some of the data i get from the database. However i have a problem with HOUR! Why am i not getting this value? Where am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();


$update_ime=$_POST['ime'];
$update_priimek=$_POST['priimek'];
$update_email=$_POST['email'];
$update_telefon=$_POST['telefon'];
$update_izobrazba=$_POST['izobrazba'];
$update_kraj=$_POST['kraj'];
$id_posta = $_POST['prijava_na_datum'];

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DATUM, HOUR FROM razpisani_tecaji WHERE ID_TECAJA = '$id_posta'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$date = $row['DATUM']; 
$hour = $row['HOUR']; 

$to      = 'info@viverius.com,rok.ivartnik@viverius-education.com';
$subject = 'prijava_na_tecaj_fizicna';
$headers = "Prijavljam se na tečaj dne: " . $date . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Ob: " . $hour . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Ime: " . $update_ime . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Priimek: " . $update_priimek . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Email: " . $update_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Telefon: " . $update_telefon . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Status/izobrazba: " . $update_izobrazba . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Ime ustanove/kraja: " . $update_kraj . "\r\n";




if(@mail($to, $subject, $headers)){
 header('Location: email_uspesno_poslan.html'); exit;
}else{
 header('Location: email_neuspesno_poslan.html'); exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: your mail failed, for one thing.

Comment: You also should use full/proper bracing.

Comment: Remove the error suppressor around the mail function. Then use php's error_get_last()

Comment: mail didnt fail...i got the mail, but HOUR missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$row` is empty when you try to get the `HOUR` key:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
$date = $row['DATUM']; 
$hour = $row['HOUR'];
```

evaluates to:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = $row['DATUM']; 
}
$hour = $row['HOUR'];
```

So `$row` is empty / `null` when you try to use it.

And you need to read-up on sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of a while statement is simple. It tells PHP to execute the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression evaluates to TRUE. The value of the expression is checked each time at the beginning of the loop, so even if this value changes during the execution of the nested statement(s), execution will not stop until the end of the iteration (each time PHP runs the statements in the loop is one iteration). Sometimes, if the while expression evaluates to FALSE from the very beginning, the nested statement(s) won't even be run once.

Like with the if statement, you can group multiple statements within the same while loop by surrounding a group of statements with curly braces, or by using the alternate syntax:

```
while (expr):
    statement
    ...
endwhile;
```

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)